# drupal 7 theming concepts extension in drupal 8 theming layer

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

i'm part time wordpress theme designer.Last week i started learning drupal 7 theming. My question is,will drupal 7 theming concepts extended in drupal 8 theming layer or drupal8 theming layer completely different from drupal 7 layer.Whether i continue learning process or wait till august 2013,code freeze month for drupal 8. Drupal expertise please help me.i seek for answers based on future prospective.Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're completely different. Drupal 8 [will use Twig](http://drupal.org/node/1499460)

Comment: thankx bro,Is render array legacy continue in drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

The way i had known Drupal, am pretty sure it would be only until second quarter of 2014 at the latest that you would find people using D8 in production sites.

Compared to D5 to D6 transition, D6 to D7 transition was not that complicated. But in D8 its going to be different. Drupal is going to shake hands with [symphony](http://symfony.com/) which is going to effect many functions in D8's theme layer for sure.

**Current scenario with d7**

The flexibility ( aka complexity ) of Field API that was introduced in D7 along with its formatters have influenced Theme layer programming a lot. As a matter of fact there exists more than one way (than there ever was ) to theme an element in Drupal. Also note that lots of module like display suite, panels, Views ( yeah views ) could also be used to configure the layout from UI.  Also for responsive designs we have Mothership, Omega and Adaptive themes supporting lots of configuration via UI.

Since most of these work ( UI ) are usually carried forward in to next Drupal versions, i.e. D8, and if you would be using it for theming then its would be worth spending time on it now.

If you intend to spend lot of time in theme layer alone then i believe you would have to learn things again when you would do project in D8, but like i had stated earlier, you would get some six months atleast to practice on it before you would actually use it for production sites.

The template/theming engine is not necessari

Comment: I have read about some discussion about render elements being used instead of render arrays. But am not sure what it is. You can read about major theme changes in the following links. 
http://drupal.org/node/1831138
http://drupal.org/node/1823416